# Exception has occurred. FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <br /> ^ )

Tags: php, flutter, dart

[image]i'm trying to make SignUp function using flutter and PHP as backend and all the code is working fin so it register successfully but the problem Appear whan i'm trying to register again by using the same username or password so i tryed to solve the problem and i find the error is come from the function (validateUsername and validateEmails) exactly in the code when i check if the email or username is exist so i don't know what is the problem in the code i see it is true

i tryed to disable these code and it work fin but it add the same email and username again and i don't wan that happen
code for username

```
$query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:un");
        $query->bindParam(":un", $un);
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowCount() != 0) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$usernameTaken);
        }
```

code for email

```
$query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:em");
        $query->bindParam(":em", $em);
        $query->execute();

        if ($query->rowCount() != 0) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$emailTaken);
            return true;
        }
```

this is my code in flutter

```
signUp() async {
    formdata = formStateSignUp.currentState;
    if (formdata.validate()) {
      formdata.save();
      showloading(context);
      var data = {
        "firstName": firstName.text,
        "lastName": lastName.text,
        "username": username.text,
        "email": email.text,
        "confirmEmail": confirmEmail.text,
        "password": password.text,
        "confirmPassword": confirmPassword.text,
      };

      var url = "http://10.0.2.2/videoTube/SignUp.php";
      var response = await http.post(url, body: data);
      var responsebody = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responsebody);
      if (responsebody['status'] == "success") {
        //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("homepage");
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        showdialogall(
          context,
          "Error",
          "This email already exist",
        );
      }
    } else {
      print("not vaild");
    }
  }
```

this is the code for SignUp page

```
    <?php

include "config.php";
require_once("class/FormSanitizer.php");
require_once("class/Account.php");
require_once("class/Constants.php");


$account = new Account($con);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    if (isset($_POST["firstName"]) && isset($_POST["lastName"]) && isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["confirmEmail"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["confirmPassword"])) {

          $firstName = FormSanitizer::sanitizeFormString($_POST["firstName"]);
          $lastName = FormSanitizer::sanitizeFormString($_POST["lastName"]);

          $username = FormSanitizer::sanitizeFormUsername($_POST["username"]);

          $email = FormSanitizer::sanitizeFormEmail($_POST["email"]);
          $confirmEmail = FormSanitizer::sanitizeFormEmail($_POST["confirmEmail"]);

          $password = FormSanitizer::sanitizeFormPassword($_POST["password"]);
          $confirmPassword = FormSanitizer::sanitizeFormPassword($_POST["confirmPassword"]);



          //echo json_encode(array('firstname' => $firstName, 'lastName' => $lastName, 'username' => $username, 'email' => $email, 'confirmEmail' => $confirmEmail, 'password' => $password, 'confirmPassword' => $confirmPassword));

          $wasSuccessful = $account->register($firstName, $lastName, $username, $email, $confirmEmail, $password, $confirmPassword);

          if ($wasSuccessful) {
              echo json_encode(array('firstName' => $firstName, 'lastName' => $lastName, 'username' => $username, 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => "success"));
          } 
          else {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => "faild"));
          }
          echo $account->getError(Constants::$firstNameCharacters);
          echo $account->getError(Constants::$lastNameCharacters);
          echo $account->getError(Constants::$usernameCharacters);
          echo $account->getError(Constants::$uaernameTaken);
          echo $account->getError(Constants::$emailsDoNotMatch);
          echo $account->getError(Constants::$emailInvalid);
          echo $account->getError(Constants::$emailTaken);
          echo $account->getError(Constants::$passwordsDoNotMatch);
          echo $account->getError(Constants::$passwordNotAlphanumeric);
          echo $account->getError(Constants::$passwordLength);

    }
}

?>
```

and this is the code for Account page which contain (validateUsername and validateEmails) function

```
    <?php

class Account {

    private $con;
    private $errorArray = array();

    public function __construct($con) {
        $this->con = $con;
    }
    
    public function register($fn, $ln, $un, $em, $em2, $pw, $pw2) {
        $this->validateFirstName($fn);
        $this->validateLastName($ln);
        $this->validateUsername($un);
        $this->validateEmails($em, $em2);
        $this->validatePasswords($pw, $pw2);

        if (empty($this->errorArray)) {
            return $this->insertUserDetails($fn, $ln, $un, $em, $pw);
        }
         else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function insertUserDetails($fn, $ln, $un, $em, $pw) {

        $pw = hash("sha512", $pw);
        $profilePic = "assets/images/profilePictures/default.png";

        $query = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, username, email, password, profilePic) VALUES (:fn, :ln, :un, :em, :pw, :pic)");
        $query->bindParam(":fn", $fn);
        $query->bindParam(":ln", $ln);
        $query->bindParam(":un", $un);
        $query->bindParam(":em", $em);
        $query->bindParam(":pw", $pw);
        $query->bindParam(":pic", $profilePic);

        return $query->execute();

    }
    
    private function validateFirstName($fn) {
        if(strlen($fn) > 25 || strlen($fn) < 2) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$firstNameCharacters);
        }
    }
    private function validateLastName($ln) {
        if (strlen($ln) > 25 || strlen($ln) < 2) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$lastNameCharacters);
        }
    }

    private function validateUsername($un) {
        if(strlen($un) > 25 || strlen($un) < 5) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$usernameCharacters);
            return;
        }

        $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:un");
        $query->bindParam(":un", $un);
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowCount() != 0) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$usernameTaken);
        }

    }
    private function validateEmails($em, $em2) {
        if($em != $em2) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$emailsDoNotMatch);
            return;
        }

        if(!filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$emailInvalid);
            return;
        }

        $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:em");
        $query->bindParam(":em", $em);
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowCount() != 0) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$emailTaken);
        }

    }

    private function validatePasswords($pw, $pw2) {
        if ($pw != $pw2) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$passwordsDoNotMatch);
            return;
        }

        if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", $pw)) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$passwordNotAlphanumeric);
            return;
        }

        if (strlen($pw) > 30 || strlen($pw) < 5) {
            array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$passwordLength);
            return;
        }
    }
    
    public function getError($error) {
        if(in_array($error, $this->errorArray)) {
            return json_encode($error);
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: In which line is the Exception thrown? You might also have some grammar mistakes there ... `echo $account->getError(Constants::$uaernameTaken);` (`$uaernameTaken`), `echo json_encode(array('status' => "faild"));` (`"faild"`)

Comment: it is not gives the line that have the Exception